# Creating lists of random length in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a program in python. In it, I want to generate a list. This list will start at one and increment by one `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.]`.

However, I want the length of the list to be random, between 3 numbers and 8 numbers long. For example, on one run the list might generate `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, on another it might generate `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, another run might generate `[1, 2, 3]`, and so on.

I know how to make a list generate random numbers but not so that it increments numbers at a random length. Thank you for your time. I am using Python 2.7 by the way.

Comment: `range(1,random.randint(4,9))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just

```
l1 = [ i + 1 for i in range(randint(...)  ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import random
start = 1
end = random.randint(3, 8)
l = range(start, end + 1)
```

Comment: You want `random.randint(3, 9)` there.

Comment: This at times will generate only two numbers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out :-) hope this minor problems can be solved by the op himself (though i have corrected my answer)

Comment: probably better will be `range(start, start+end)`

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using range() where the first argument is the start and the second argument is the random length

```
import random
range(1, random.randint(3, 8))
```

Answer (score 2):

An itertools approach - which also means if you don't need to materialise the list, then you don't have to:

```
from itertools import count, islice
from random import randint

mylist = list(islice(count(1), randint(3, 8)))
```

Since `count` is a generator incrementing by 1 each time, we use `islice` to "limit" the total number of items we take from it, and then build a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint  
l = range(1,randint(3,8)+1 )
print l
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify 4 at the bottom end and 9 as the top of `randint` you'll get up to 8 numbers like you ask for. **You need to do** this because you start the `range` at 1.

```
>>> import random
>>> range(1, random.randint(4,4))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> range(1, random.randint(9,9))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> rand_list = range(1, random.randint(4,9))
>>> rand_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

[`Range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=range#range) first argument is the starting point. The 2nd argument is the stop. Many of the other answers will sometimes return only two numbers, in the cases where `stop == 3`.

```
>>> range(1,3)
[1, 2]
>>> range(1,4)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> range(1,8)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> range(1,9)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Why isn't my answer useful?